# my checkbox pass value even unchecked - Grails

Tags: grails, checkbox, gsp

I have lots of `checkbox` element on my Grails `form`, one is this:

```
<g:checkBox id="consolidate" name="consolidate" value="${true}" checked="${false}" />
```

Then on the receiving `controller`, I verify the value of the `checkbox` using this `code`:

```
println params?.consolidate
```

And it displays:

```
on
```

Regardless whether I've tick my checkbox or not. In other language, if the checkbox is not ticked, its value on the controller will be `null` or `undefined`. What should be its value when unchecked, and what is the right code to access its value on the grails controller?

**Temporary Solution:**

The following code (on `JavaScript`) is what I had used temporarily to accommodate my requirement. Though what I want is an explanation or maybe correction about this behavior.

```
var serialized_string = "";
$("#form input").each(function(i, j) {
    var o = $(j);
    if(o.val() !== undefined && o.val() !== "undefined" && o.val() !== "") {
        if(serialized_string === "") {
            serialized_string += o.attr("name") + "=";
        }
        else {
            if(o.attr("name") === "consolidate") {
                var val = "false";
                if(o.prop("checked")) {
                    val = "true";
                }
                data += val;
            }
            else {
                data += "&" + o.attr("name") + "=";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the source of the rendered checkbox look like? Hint your issue has something to do with `checked="${false}"`

Comment: @joshua I've also tried without the `checked` tag, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: because checkbox value is true.

Comment: @user1690588 **Does it not works like this**: if the checkbox is checked then its value when passed to controller is whatever the value in the `value` tag, and if it's not checked, then its value is `null`; or does it get to passed regardless whether it is checked or not?

Comment: Why you can't add hidden field, that will be update by javascript(onclick) value?

Comment: Of course @Koloritnij . Well, I can also use that solution, among other solutions available, but what I really want is to know the root cause of this _misbehavior_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If checked, you see the **on** you're seeing; otherwise you see **null**, which is your **false**.

Comment: But regardless whether it is `checked` or `unchecked`, it always pass `on` value.

Comment: Strange! I ran into the same issue a while ago. I had a table where two columns of which were used for checkboxes with no domain object to bind to. Inspection through println of the entire params map showed that there were only two values a checkbox assumes: **on** or **null**.